# Azure AD SSO for independent App Registrations

Tags: firebase, azure, single-sign-on

I need to provide an SSO between two independent applications via the Azure AD SSO.

My app (`A`) use Firebase as the backend and currently isn't registered in Azure AD.
The second App (`B`) is registered in Azure AD via App Registration and I think has password-based login now (but it doesn't really matter). Can't say what technology it uses for the backend.

I've read a lot of Azure documentation but can't understand how exactly should I connect them with SSO.

I see that I can connect applications from the Enterprise Applications list. Is this the only way to do it? In this case, I need to [publish](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-howto-app-gallery-listing) my app to the Enterprise Applications gallery but it feels like an overcomplicated solution.

Answer (score 2):

SSO feature and experience depends on the type of auth-protocol being used. It also varies based on that. Lets say, your app uses OpenIDConnect then the SSO experience would be something like what mentioned here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/configure-oidc-single-sign-on
If it uses SAML as the auth-protocol it looks something similar to: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/configure-saml-single-sign-on
and if its using Password-based SSO then: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/configure-password-single-sign-on-non-gallery-applications

Specifically for Password-Based SSO, it provides SSO by storing the credentials in the browser extension. With password-based sign-on, users sign on to the application with a username and password the first time they access it. After the first sign-on, Azure AD supplies the username and password to the application.

Password-based single sign-on uses the existing authentication process provided by the application. When you enable password single sign-on for an application, Azure AD collects and securely stores user names and passwords for the application.

**Choose password-based single sign-on when:**

- An application doesn't support SAML single sign-on protocol.
- An application authenticates with a username and password instead of access tokens and headers.

In your case, both you apps (MyApp-A and MyApp-B) needs to be registered in AAD and they should support neither SAML or OIDC.